# Object does not exist at location android studio Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I wanna store an image in firebase storage but i got an warning message when running "Object does not exist at location", I don't know where is my mistake, already trying search old answer but all of them in java not kotlin.

```
class Activity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var curFile: Uri? = null
    private val imageRef = Firebase.storage.reference
    private val  REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_PICK = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2)

        //an image view to select and image inside phone storage
        ivfoto.setOnClickListener {
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).also {
                it.type = "image/*"
                startActivityForResult(it, REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_PICK)
            }
        }
        //btn for upload image to storage
        btnupload.setOnClickListener {
            uploadImageToStorage("Myimages")
        }

    }
    //function to upload an image to firebase
    private fun uploadImageToStorage(filename: String) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            curFile?.let {
                imageRef.child("images/$filename").putFile(it).await()
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@Activity2, "Foto anda telah dipilih",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                Toast.makeText(this@Activity2, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_PICK) {
                data?.data?.let {
                    curFile = it
                    ivfoto.setImageURI(it)
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

[Here is the error message,its on the device,already run in physical device and emulator but the error is the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XdyA.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the full error log please?

Comment: I already re edit and put the error message as you can see in my device,there is no error log cause the app actually running,but the error messagge "object does not exist at location" i dont know why its happen so the function for upload image doesnt work